# Declaring the charAt()

Tags: java, charat

```
String txt="Hello world";
int count;

for(int x = 0; x <= txt.length(); x++) {
    if (txt.charAt(x) == ' ') {
        count++;
    }
}
```

My app was force closing after declaring the `charAt()`, is there any problem with this? & how can i fix it?

Comment: You're iterating past the bounds of the string: change `<= l.length()` to `< l.length()`.

Comment: You aren't `declaring' `charAt()`. You are *callng* it. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: yeah that's how it is .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indices start at 0.

For example,

```
String str = "foo"
```

Is a string of length 3. However, when we count the characters of the string we start at 0 which corresponds to 'f' and end at 2 which corresponds to 'o'.

The code,

```
String str = "foo"; 
for(int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Is incorrect because it counts from 0 to 3.

```
String str = "foo"; 
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    // ...
}
```

is correct because it counts from 0 to 2.

Comment: It works... :) thanks for the help, I really appreciated it!